# How to optimistically update data using useMutation

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I want to update a record in a database. So far `EditTodoList` is updating the corresponding record in the db perfectly. My problem is with the optimistic update part  the changes only show after refetching `"TODO_LIST"+projectId` query, even though this `useMutation` setup I have is  supposed to be reflect the changes instantly in the ui.

I didn't face this problem when creating the todoList because in `onMutate`  I just needed to do this  `queryClient.setQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId,(old)=>[...old,newTodoList])`, but this case I need to change `old` array.

```
return useMutation(
    EditTodoList,
    {
      onSuccess:(newProject)=>queryClient.setQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId,(old)=>[...old,newProject]),

      onMutate:(values)=>{
         const {title,projectId,todos,todoListToBeEdited}=values
         queryClient.cancelQueries("TODO_LIST"+projectId)

         const previousData=queryClient.getQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId)

         //update query data
         let temp=[...previousData]
         const targetTodoList=temp.filter(tds=>tds.id === todoListToBeEdited.id)[0]
         const targetTodoListIndex=temp.indexOf(targetTodoList)
     
         const newTodoList =  TodoListModel(projectId,title,todoListToBeEdited.orderInProject)
     
         temp[targetTodoListIndex] = newTodoList
     
         //this is where I need help , the setQueryData seems to ignore temp even though temp has the latest up-to-date data  
         queryClient.setQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId,(old)=>[...temp])
         return  queryClient.setQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId,previousData)
      },

      onError:(err,values,rollBack)=>rollBack()
    }
)
```

Answer (score 1):

the suggested way is:

- optimistically update in `onMutate` with `setQueryData`. If you have a list, yes, it means iterating over that list and finding the right element to update.
- return something to rollback
- rollback on error
- invalidate `onSettled` to refetch the query in any case to be in-sync with the server state. This is optional, if your optimistic update is "perfect" (like just toggling a boolean), there's sometimes no need to do that.

There's a whole section about optimistic updates [in the docs](https://react-query.tanstack.com/guides/optimistic-updates), and there are also [codesandbox examples](https://react-query.tanstack.com/examples/optimistic-updates)

/edit: sorry, I missed the comment about the `setQueryData`. If you have computed the next data already, you don't need to use the functional updater. This should work:

`queryClient.setQueryData("TODO_LIST"+projectId, temp)`